# What part of a fragment's lifecycle is activated by user tapping the overflow menu "settings dots icon"?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

When the user hits the "settings dots" and pops up the menu shown, I want the timer to stop immediately (i.e., before user picks from the list), but I don't know where to put `Timer.pauseTimer()`.

When the user taps one of the 4 items in the dropdown list, `MainActivity.onOptionsSelected()` is activated and I can pause the timer, but how do I get control at the *instant* the dots icon is tapped?

I had hoped `onAttach` would do it in the `SettingsFragment`, but no. Timer ticks away with the screen looking as shown below.

[image]

Comment: You want to use [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)).

Comment: You're right--that's what gets called all right. My problem now (requiring a different question if I can't figure it out myself) is that the timer doesn't stop every time (it does sometimes!) even though I have this code: `@Override public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
Timer.pauseTimer("Main onPrepOptMenu");
return true;}`

Comment: That'll definitely need a new question since you'll have to provide and post  your code. You can reference this question if you need context for the new one.

Comment: I may have figured out the "iffy-ness"--there's a delay before the next flag is shown. If user taps overflow dots BEFORE next flag shows, timer does NOT stop. If user waits until next flag shows, it does.